# Probability of the last card being the largest

Tags: probability

Can someone help me out with this one? Can't figure it out. I think it will be something trivial...

> > We have cards numbered from $1 \dots 20$. Let's pick $4$ cards (we pick first card then second etc). What is the probability that the 4th card will be the largest of the four cards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(hint) do not consider the other 16 cards, they are irrelevant.
Among the four picked cards, one has the largest value.

Comment: still no idea ^^

Comment: you have four cards in a casual order. Do you agree that the probability that the 4th card has the highest value is the same as the probability that the **first** card has the highest value? If so, which is the probability that you are picking the highest valued card first in a set of four cards?

Comment: (your problem gives useless information: in general, you should always try to see what really matters and what it is added just to confound you)

Comment: But isn't that probability dependent on the cards I pick?

Comment: why should it be? you are searching for the highest card **among the four you picked**. You may just rename their values to 1,2,3,4 if you want; the only important thing is that if original value of card A is less than original value of card B, then the renamed value of A must be less that that of B.

Comment: Is it $\frac3{32}$ ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8049/discussion-between-mau-and-david-kaya)